# Splitting Python list to smaller substrings

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am trying to separate a single list into separate two sub-strings and then append them like key,value in dictionary.

The approach i tried is to split the list into smaller sub-strings then **append the item at index 0 as key and index 1 as value in dictionary**.

E.g

**Input test.txt**

```
Writing Fast Tests Against Enterprise Rails 60min
Overdoing it in Python 45min
```

**Expected Output**

```
    {'Writing Fast Tests Against Enterprise Rails': 60,
     'Overdoing it in Python': 45}
```

My approach so far has been into slicing the list into smaller sub-strings.

```
d = {}

lines = [line.strip() for line in open('test.txt')]

for line in lines:
    print(line.split(maxsplit=1))
```

The above code produces the following output

```
['Writing', 'Fast Tests Against Enterprise Rails 60min']
['Overdoing', 'it in Python 45min']
```

How to slice the list such that it slices the names and time into sub-strings and then append it to a dict.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @Ashwini, i got the correct output. It was simple.

```
d = {}

lines = [line.strip() for line in open('test.txt')]

for line in lines:
    title, minutes = line.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
    d[title] = int(minutes[:-3])

print(d)
```